# Iterating struct array by pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, arrays, struct, pointer-arithmetic

I'm trying to iterate over an array of structs by pointer arithmetic. However it gives me results I can't understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
} Time;

void time_print(Time t)
{
    printf("Time is: %d:%d:%d\n", t.hours, t.minutes, t.seconds);
}

int main(void)
{    
    Time *testTimePointers[2];

    testTimePointers[0] = malloc(sizeof(Time));
    testTimePointers[0]->hours = 11;
    testTimePointers[0]->minutes = 10;
    testTimePointers[0]->seconds = 9;

    testTimePointers[1] = malloc(sizeof(Time));
    testTimePointers[1]->hours = 7;
    testTimePointers[1]->minutes = 6;
    testTimePointers[1]->seconds = 5;

    time_print(*(testTimePointers[0]));
    time_print(*(testTimePointers[1]));

    printf("=============\n");


    Time *ttp_cur = NULL;
    ttp_cur = testTimePointers[0];

    time_print(*(ttp_cur));

    ttp_cur++;

    time_print(*(ttp_cur));


    free(testTimePointers[0]);
    free(testTimePointers[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Results in

```
Time is: 11:10:9 
Time is: 7:6:5
=============
Time is: 11:10:9
Time is: 0:0:0
```

In the second block, the second line should be `Time is: 7:6:5` instead of `Time is: 0:0:0`.

Comment: After `ttp_cur++;` pointer makes step equal to sizeof(Time) and points to nowhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that in the second part of the program you mean the following

```
    //...

    Time **ttp_cur = testTimePointers;

    time_print(**ttp_cur );

    ttp_cur++;

    time_print(**ttp_cur);


    free(testTimePointers[0]);
    free(testTimePointers[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

If you have an array like

```
T a[2];
```

where `T` is some type specifier then the pointer to its first element is declared the following way

```
T *p = a;
```

and expression

++p;

will point to the second element of the array.

Now if to consider your array

```
Time *testTimePointers[2];
```

then type specifier `T` will be equal to `Time *`. So the declaration of the pointer to the first element of the array will look like

```
Time **ttp_cur = testTimePointers;
```

and expression

```
++ttp_cur;
```

will point to the second element of the array.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you are trying to increment a pointer `ttp_cur` that does not point to an array.

The value you are trying to increment, `ttp_cur`, came from `testTimePointers[0]`, which in turn came from `malloc` of a single `struct Time`, not an array. That's why when you increment that pointer, the behavior is undefined.

It would be OK to increment a pointer pointing to `testTimePointers` array, however. If you did this

```
Time **ttp_cur_p = testTimePointers;
time_print(*(*ttp_cur_p));
ttp_cur_p++;
time_print(*(*ttp_cur_p));
```

you would get the results that you expect ([demo](http://ideone.com/1Jjy9d)).